# Chrome Extension - Modify Right-Click Browser Action Menu

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, browser-action

I am wondering if I am able to modify the right-click menu of the browser action menu? I want to add an option titled 'Logout'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you cant do that, youll need to stick it in the browser actions popup.

Comment: Darn it. Thanks for letting me know though :)

Comment: Now possible; updated information in [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26349835/934239).

Answer (score 15):

For the context Chrome says:

> Value must be one of: `[all, page, frame, selection, link, editable, image, video, audio, launcher, browser_action, page_action]`

So use

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title": "Logout",
  "contexts": ["browser_action"],
  "onclick": logout
});
```

Where `logout()` is the function that will be called when you click on it. (And enable "contextMenus" permission in the manifest.)

**Edit:** A bit of warning, if you have an [Event page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages), using `onclick` attribute is not supported and you should add a `chrome.contextMenus.onClicked` handler instead.

Comment: To be fair: this answer is new, as this only hit Stable in Chrome 38. But that' is the **new correct answer**.

Answer (score 0):

It's now `action` context, not `browser_action`. Although I don't understand the difference and got no errors or warnings. Documentations says nothing. Thanks to https://stackoverflow.com/a/70209019/2630849

Answer (score -3):

hum, if i understand ... you want add item on menu after right click?

You can do this :

```
chrome.contextMenus.create({
  "title" : "You menu Name",
  "type" : "normal",
  "contexts" : ["link","video","audio"], //the context which item appear
  "onclick" : shorten() // The function call on click
});
```

And your manifest :

Add "contextMenus" on "permissions" array.

More information : [here](http://u.troll.sh/JAft9)

Comment: No, you don't understand. Jon asked about the browser action menu, not the page context menu.